# Feasibility of using blockchain to avoid researcher bias

Tags: research-process, experiment-design

Would it be feasible, presently or in the future, to use computers with blockchain technology to help avoid researcher bias?

For instance, in a medical experiment, when an experimenter uses blockchain to store data gathered by interviewers about a patient's condition after a new medication, he/she would be able to guarantee that it would be literally impossible to change the results to fit the expected outcome.

Comment: When people talking about others fudging results, it's not usually the veracity of the data itself that is in question; rather it's researchers who -- through malice or misunderstanding -- use questionable statistical methods. Straight-up falsifying data is rare, *p*-hacking, less so.

Comment: It might be a solution for changing data, but how would it avoid bias? Bias can occur immediately  when the data is collected and entered. Even automatically collected data can be altered if you control the software that collects it.

Comment: Slightly relevant: https://www.xkcd.com/2030/

Comment: I was thinking about a case when researcher intentionally use p-hacking or data falsification from accurate results collected by interviewers. So blockchain might be able to prevent data from being manipulated by researchers in a foolproof way.

Comment: Why blockchain? That's complete overkill. Upload your datasets onto your university's public archiving system. Everything will be signed and versioned and that's it.

Comment: What do you mean by researcher bias?

Comment: @JayLee That is not what p-hacking means.

Comment: @Karl It is not overkill to use blockchains for this reason since it is very inexpensive to use blockchain to prove that the data has not been changed after the Merkle root of the data has been posted to a blockchain and since public archiving systems can and should do this completely automatically. This is an inexpensive solution.

Comment: In this question, we need to be specific about how researchers should use blockchains to avoid research bias and even what kind of blockchain should be used. I see no mention of any specific blockchain or kind of blockchain anywhere in this question. This is important since it will give people of how feasible the solution will be.

Answer (score 2):

While blockchain might be a good solution for certain (future?) applications in research, experiments, and data collection – it is hard to shine a lot of light on it right now, as the technology is pretty new. And research techniques, scientific methodology, experiment design, and, most importantly, ethical standards have been (and will be) developed for centuries.

Most importantly, a lot of interaction between scientists is (and should be) based on trust and an assumption of good intentions.

---

This particular question focuses on researcher bias; however, the example is more about data manipulation or "forced outcome" research.

Regarding data-manipulation:

- As correctly mentioned in the comments (@AzorAhai), it is rare to forge the raw data itself, but use certain statistical techniques to get to the desired outcome.
- Using blockchain would have to be introduced on a lot of levels: not necessarily just the surveys. Blockchain for measurement equipment (which constitutes a lot of experimental data in natural sciences) is not yet there. And if one allows a researcher (how crazy is that!) to upload measurement data himself to blockchain-based storage – nothing prevents the researcher from forging data before uploading it.
- Not being able to change the data might not always be a good thing. Sometimes, you have to change it (simple use – delete certain entries) due to technical (it was found that the equipment was broken) or ethical reasons. Here the "permanency" advantage of blockchain might actually be damaging. For example, even git (version-control system not allowing commit change without the change of the signature) has some widely discussed issues: [ACCU talk of Alex Chan, the particular segment on GIT and personal info issues](https://youtu.be/qi4bMw7tyKk?t=969).

So, regarding the experiment data, I currently do not see the advantages of using blockchain anywhere in the research loop.

I can see some potential use of blockchain in:

- review process (though, I would say it's an overkill) to anonymize authors/reviewers/editors. However, there are other simpler tools to solve it – and even they are rarely used in practice.
- authorship proof – still there are other tools.

To conclude:

I am very interested to see practical uses of blockchain in other areas (let's see where the smart contracts go in 5-10 years). Academia and research process does not scream for blockchain and its usability is totally unclear and hard to implement.

Comment: Which kinds of blockchains are you referring to? And what protocol that is designed to prevent data manipulation are you referring to?

Comment: "Not being able to change the data might not always be a good thing."-Posting timestamps on blockchains does not prevent anyone from changing the data. This procedure only forces people to give a more honest explanation about it since if they want to change their data, they will need a new timestamp along with an explanation for why the data is being changed. Of course, it is hard for me to comment since I will need to know what protocol you have in mind.

Comment: @JosephVanName I am referring to blockchains in general. I don't believe I refer to ANY protocol that prevents data manipulation.

Comment: You cannot criticize the potential use of blockchains in facilitating scientific research when you are unspecific about how you expect them to be used. I personally do not know of any blockchain protocol that makes data manipulation impossible, but there is a big gap between making data manipulation completely impossible and making data manipulation more difficult.

Comment: @JosephVanName 1) Please carefully read my post. I do not criticize blockchains for facilitating scientific research in general, I also fail to see exactly how they will be used. 2) I provide thoughts and justifications of the current status quo. Not that it cannot be changed. 3) I provide reasons outside of blockchain, why data is handled the way it is now. 4) I provide my view on blockchain, as well as personal opinion that academia and research process does not scream for it.

Comment: I did carefully read your post, but I was concerned because it is hard to tell whether someone is talking about creating a completely new blockchain for scientific research and having digital contracts on blockchains completely guide the research or whether you are talking about a simpler solution that does not require too much effort.

Comment: The simplest solution that can be used to prevent data manipulation will be for researchers to post timestamps of the data on the Bitcoin blockchain. Here, one cannot change the data without changing the timestamps. This solution is effective, inexpensive, easy to implement, and it does not compromise on anyone's privacy/security. Your concerns do not apply to these timestamps.

Comment: @JosephVanName "Not being able to change the data" - is a reference to the original question. Please, consider my answer TOGETHER with the question being asked, its intentions, and phrasing.

Comment: I am not sure about what your concern is. I am more concerned about which protocol is implemented since one protocol could be extremely expensive, difficult, and not suitable for its purpose (i.e. making a digital contract guide all of the research) while my suggested protocol is inexpensive and does not have any serious downsides that I can think of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124688/discussion-between-anton-menshov-and-joseph-van-name).